# OpenServer: Сервер запускается, но в браузере страница не открывается, подробности в приложенном видео

Tags: apache, http, openserver

Такая проблема, cервер запускается, но в браузере страница не открывается, всё в видео по ссылке:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KbwGAREEN_VIVjNmm2whPMMnk3N0tNog/view

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать! Заранее спасибо!

P.S. В вебе я новенький.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас стоит галочка "не вносить изменения в HOSTS файл". Именно через него OpenServer задет домен вместо простого localhost.
Снимите галочку и перезапустите OpenServer от имени Администратора.

---

Если вас бесит каждый раз запускать от имени Администратора - есть лютый костыль. Можно перестроить права доступа на HOSTS файл (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) для простого юзера. Это очень небезопасно, открывает безконечное поле для фишинга, но если вам не страшно - можете делать только на свой страх и риск!

---

Второй вариант - добавить домены в HOSTS файл вручную. Для этого добавьте следующую строчку в HOSTS файл:

```
127.0.0.1 domain-name
```

, где `domain-name` - имя домена. (`peredachka` в вашем случае). Таких строк можно добавлять сколько угодно.

Comment: РЕШЕНО! в свойствах файла выставил "запукать от админа для всех", спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с подобным и нашел простое решение. Скопировать содержимое файла hosts, удалить и создать его от обычного пользователя. После вставить содержимое из буфера обмена.

P.S. Сохранять файл нужно из любого текстового редактора, потому что OC не даст создать файл без расширения через правый клик.